# How to push values into array after converting object into string using JSON.stringify(object) in Angular 6

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, arraylist

I have declared an Array as `public answers: Answers[] = [];` Here Answers is my class which is as below:

```
export class Answers {
    question : string;
    answer : string;
}
```

Now I am adding values into `answers` as below:

```
public addAnswersToStack() {
    AnswerEmitterService.get('answer').subscribe((data: Answers) => {
      var isPresent = this.answers.some((el) => {
        return el[0] === data[0];
      });
      console.log(isPresent);
      if (isPresent == true) {
        let indexValue = this.answers.findIndex(obj => obj.question == data.question);
        console.log("Index Value =>" + indexValue);
        this.answers[indexValue] = JSON.stringify(data);
        this.uniqueAnswers = Array.from(new Set(this.answers));
      } else {
        this.answers.push(JSON.stringify(data));
        this.uniqueAnswers = Array.from(new Set(this.answers));
      }
      console.log("Answers=>" + this.answers);
    });
  }
```

The error I am getting is => ERROR : Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type answers in `this.answers.push(JSON.stringify(data));` .

I have tried `this.answers.push(data);`. After doing this I am getting values in array as :
 `Do you Have Multiple locations?,yes,How many Physical locations?,23,Corporate billing info,coporate`

Due to this whenever I try to update value of array it is updating in 0(zero) index of `this.answers`.

```
let indexValue = this.answers.findIndex(obj => obj.question == data.question);
        console.log("Index Value =>" + indexValue);
        this.answers[indexValue] = data;
```

However, I am getting index value as -1 (sometimes). Can someone please suggest me how to store values in an array such that i can update those values after finding index based on question (of model class).

Comment: Try this this `data.foreach((d)=>.answers.push(question:d[0],answer:d[1]))`

Comment: Indeed why would you want stringify here?

Answer (score 0):

Do not convert your object to string by using `JSON.stringify()` function.

Just change

```
JSON.stringify(data);
```

to

```
data;
```

Everywhere.